# How to create a custom messagebox in windows phone 7 that allows for a hyperlink

Tags: windows-7

I'm looking for a way to have a hyperlink that's inside my messagebox.show() be something the user can click on. Is it possible to build this behavior in if I subclass Messagebox?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Tried to keep things simple, here is more detail.

This is not possible through the standard message box offered in wp7. The best way is to create your own message box. This is pretty simple, you can follow the example in my [blog post](http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2011/11/13/Creating-a-Custom-MessageBox-for-Windows-Phone-Applications.aspx). My blog does not explain adding a hyperlink, but this can be easily done by adding the hyperlink into the control and add another parameter to the Show method.

Comment: A couple of links does not an answer make.  Paraphrase the external stuff here.